# SQL Server, how to execute a job against all databases on server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to find the best way to execute a query against all databases on the server using SQLServerAgent or maintenance plan.

I have a stored procedure that I'd like to run on these databases, but I cannot create the stored procedure in these databases.

I tried experimenting with using `exec sp_msforeachdb` and `DECLARE @command = '<my sp>'` but I ran into the problem with escaping too many single quotes '.

So in the end, I'd like to say something like:
For all databases, run this block of code. Then schedule this job with SQLServerAgent.

```
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    --DECLARE VARIABLES
    DECLARE
    @max INT,
    @min INT,
    @table_name NVARCHAR(256),
    @table_schema NVARCHAR(256),
    @sql NVARCHAR(4000)

    --DECLARE TABLE VARIABLE
    DECLARE @table TABLE(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    table_name NVARCHAR(256),
    table_schema NVARCHAR(256))

    --CREATE TEMP TABLE THAT STORES INFORMATION FROM SP_SPACEUSED
    IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#results')) IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #results
    END

    CREATE TABLE #results
    (
    [database_id] [int] NULL,
    [server_name] [nvarchar](256)  NULL, --- new, server name
    [database_name] [nvarchar](256)  NULL, --- new, db name
    [table_schema] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [table_name] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [table_rows] [int] NULL,
    [reserved_space] [nvarchar](55) NULL,
    [data_space] [nvarchar](55) NULL,
    [index_space] [nvarchar](55) NULL,
    [unused_space] [nvarchar](55) NULL
    )

    --LOOP THROUGH STATISTICS FOR EACH TABLE
    INSERT @table(table_schema, table_name)
    SELECT  
    table_schema, table_name
    FROM
    information_schema.tables 

    SELECT
    @min = 1,
    @max = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM @table)

    WHILE @min <= @max
    BEGIN
    SELECT 
    @table_name = table_name,
    @table_schema = table_schema
    FROM
    @table
    WHERE
    id = @min

    --DYNAMIC SQL
    SELECT @sql = 'EXEC sp_spaceused ''[' + @table_schema + '].[' + @table_name + ']''' --get dataA

    --INSERT RESULTS FROM SP_SPACEUSED TO TEMP TABLE
    INSERT #results(table_name, table_rows, reserved_space, data_space, index_space, unused_space)
    EXEC (@sql) --set dataA^

    --UPDATE SCHEMA NAME
    UPDATE #results
    SET table_schema = @table_schema WHERE table_name = @table_name
    UPDATE #results
    SET 
    database_id = (DB_ID()),
    server_name = (select @@SERVERNAME),
    database_name = (SELECT DB_NAME() AS [Current Database]);

    SELECT @min = @min + 1
    END

    --REMOVE "KB" FROM RESULTS FOR REPORTING (GRAPH) PURPOSES
    UPDATE #results SET data_space = SUBSTRING(data_space, 1, (LEN(data_space)-3))
    UPDATE #results SET reserved_space = SUBSTRING(reserved_space, 1, (LEN(reserved_space)-3))
    UPDATE #results SET index_space = SUBSTRING(index_space, 1, (LEN(index_space)-3))
    UPDATE #results SET unused_space = SUBSTRING(unused_space, 1, (LEN(unused_space)-3))

    --INSERT RESULTS INTO TABLESIZEGROWTH
    INSERT INTO TableSizes.dbo.TableSizeGrowth (database_id, server_name, database_name, table_schema, table_name, table_rows, reserved_space, data_space, index_space, unused_space)
    SELECT * FROM #results

    DROP TABLE #results
    END
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a SQL Agent Job with a Job Step of type "Powershell" on the SQL Server instance where your databases reside.

```
# Define the query to be run against each database
Set-Variable -Name MyQuery -Value "SELECT @@SERVERNAME"

# Access SQL Server information by using a drive and file system analogy
Set-Location "SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases"

# Get the list of databases
Get-ChildItem | Set-Variable -Name DBList

# Iterate through the list, execute your query
ForEach ( $DB in $DBList) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $MyQuery -database $DB.Name -ServerInstance 'localhost' -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

Schedule it like any other job.

Comment: Trying this on SQL Server 2016. I am getting an error on Set-Variable $MyQuery = "SELECT @@SERVERNAME". A job step received an error at line 2 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'Set-Variable $MyQuery = "SELECT @@SERVERNAME"'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null.'

Comment: I reproduced the error and revised the code. The revised code successfully executes as a SQL Agent job on my local instance of SQL Server 2016 (SP1) Developer Edition.

Answer (score 1):

This is the loop I use to go through online databases one by one, with your code inserted.

```
USE master
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @db TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), DBName NVARCHAR(500))

INSERT INTO @db (DBName)
SELECT Name FROM sys.databases WHERE state = 0 AND name <> 'tempdb'


DECLARE @Pos INT = 1, @MaxID INT, @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @MaxID = MAX(Id)
FROM @db

WHILE @Pos <= @MaxID
BEGIN

SELECT @SqlQuery = 'USE [' + DBName + '];
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    --DECLARE VARIABLES
    DECLARE
    @max INT,
    @min INT,
    @table_name NVARCHAR(256),
    @table_schema NVARCHAR(256),
    @sql NVARCHAR(4000)

    --DECLARE TABLE VARIABLE
    DECLARE @table TABLE(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    table_name NVARCHAR(256),
    table_schema NVARCHAR(256))

    --CREATE TEMP TABLE THAT STORES INFORMATION FROM SP_SPACEUSED
    IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#results'')) IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #results
    END

    CREATE TABLE #results
    (
    [database_id] [int] NULL,
    [server_name] [nvarchar](256)  NULL, --- new, server name
    [database_name] [nvarchar](256)  NULL, --- new, db name
    [table_schema] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [table_name] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [table_rows] [int] NULL,
    [reserved_space] [nvarchar](55) NULL,
    [data_space] [nvarchar](55) NULL,
    [index_space] [nvarchar](55) NULL,
    [unused_space] [nvarchar](55) NULL
    )

    --LOOP THROUGH STATISTICS FOR EACH TABLE
    INSERT @table(table_schema, table_name)
    SELECT  
    table_schema, table_name
    FROM
    information_schema.tables 

    SELECT
    @min = 1,
    @max = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM @table)

    WHILE @min <= @max
    BEGIN
    SELECT 
    @table_name = table_name,
    @table_schema = table_schema
    FROM
    @table
    WHERE
    id = @min

    --DYNAMIC SQL
    SELECT @sql = ''EXEC sp_spaceused ''''['' + @table_schema + ''].['' + @table_name + '']'''''' --get dataA

    --INSERT RESULTS FROM SP_SPACEUSED TO TEMP TABLE
    INSERT #results(table_name, table_rows, reserved_space, data_space, index_space, unused_space)
    EXEC (@sql) --set dataA^

    --UPDATE SCHEMA NAME
    UPDATE #results
    SET table_schema = @table_schema WHERE table_name = @table_name
    UPDATE #results
    SET 
    database_id = (DB_ID()),
    server_name = (select @@SERVERNAME),
    database_name = (SELECT DB_NAME() AS [Current Database]);

    SELECT @min = @min + 1
    END

    --REMOVE "KB" FROM RESULTS FOR REPORTING (GRAPH) PURPOSES
    UPDATE #results SET data_space = SUBSTRING(data_space, 1, (LEN(data_space)-3))
    UPDATE #results SET reserved_space = SUBSTRING(reserved_space, 1, (LEN(reserved_space)-3))
    UPDATE #results SET index_space = SUBSTRING(index_space, 1, (LEN(index_space)-3))
    UPDATE #results SET unused_space = SUBSTRING(unused_space, 1, (LEN(unused_space)-3))

    --INSERT RESULTS INTO TABLESIZEGROWTH
    INSERT INTO TableSizes.dbo.TableSizeGrowth (database_id, server_name, database_name, table_schema, table_name, table_rows, reserved_space, data_space, index_space, unused_space)
    SELECT * FROM #results

    DROP TABLE #results
    END'

FROM @db WHERE Id = @Pos

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlQuery

--PRINT @SqlQuery

SET @Pos = @Pos + 1

END
GO
```

Secondary to the question, but you can remove the need for looping through executing sp_spaceused for each table, grabbing all the data at once by querying the dmv's like so:

```
SELECT 
    DB_ID() AS [DatabaseId],
    @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName,
    DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName,
    SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) AS [Schema], 
    o.name AS [Object], 
    CASE o.type WHEN 'U' THEN 'Table' WHEN 'V' THEN 'View' ELSE 'Unknown' END AS [Type],
    ind.row_count,
    CAST((ind.DataSize*8.00/1024) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS DataSizeMB,
    CAST((ind.IndexSize*8.00/1024) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS IndexSizeMB,
    CAST((ind.ReservedSize*8.00/1024) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS ReservedSizeMB

from sys.objects o
inner join (
            SELECT i.object_id, MAX(ps.row_count) AS row_count,
            SUM(CASE WHEN i.index_id <= 1 THEN ps.used_page_count ELSE 0 END) AS DataSize,
            SUM(CASE WHEN i.index_id > 1 THEN ps.used_page_count ELSE 0 END) AS IndexSize,
            SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) AS ReservedSize
            FROM sys.indexes i 
            inner join sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps on ps.object_id = i.object_id and ps.index_id = i.index_id
            GROUP BY i.object_id
            ) 
        ind ON ind.object_id = o.object_id

WHERE o.type IN ('U', 'V');
```

This still needs to be looped through each database though.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Integration Services package. In the package, use a T-SQL task inside a ForEach container. The T-SQL task has the code above and the ForEach loop runs the task once for every database on a server.

Use a SQL Agent job to schedule the package.

This is how the Maintenance Plans do it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert what you have into a stored procedure which takes the database name as a parameter (change db_id() and db_name()).  Then within your scheduled job call it using

```
exec sp_msforeachdb 'exec master..mysproc @dbname=''?'''
```

Comment: Does this imply that the SP need to be stored in the master DB?