# Need to run select statement across all databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursors

I am trying to run a query like the one below across multiple databases

```
select ParamValue from Table1 where paramname = 'SYSTEM_LICENSE'
```

Each DB is named something like the one below and some DB should be excluded.

> "Customer_123"

I looked at using sp_MSforeachdb but it isn't supported and it wasn't working well. I tried figuring out how to write a cursor but was unsuccessful. At this point just looking for some help from someone who can actually write what I am looking to do.

Comment: [Making a more reliable and flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server, how to execute a job against all databases on server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53660/sql-server-how-to-execute-a-job-against-all-databases-on-server). Title says job, but really its still just a set of queries against all databases, functionally the same as this.Also [Run a script for all databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94168/run-a-script-for-all-databases/94191#94191) may be a better dup due to higher quality answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the "do something on each db" template I use, slightly adapted to your example:

```
--Create a table to hold the query results
CREATE TABLE #licenselist
    (dbid smallint, dbname sysname, system_license varchar(99));

DECLARE @fixedname nvarchar(150);

--Include or exclude whatever databases you want
DECLARE dbCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT REPLACE(QUOTENAME(name),'''','''''') --For db names with annoying characters
    FROM master.sys.databases
    WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE'
    AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1                  --Added at @SolomonRutzky's suggestion
    AND name NOT IN ('master','msdb','model','tempdb');

OPEN dbCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor INTO @fixedname;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       EXEC ('USE ' + @fixedname + ';' + 
        'INSERT INTO #licenselist
         SELECT DB_ID() as dbid, DB_NAME() as dbname, ParamValue as system_license
         FROM Table1 
         WHERE paramname = ''SYSTEM_LICENSE'';');

       FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor INTO @fixedname;
END;   

CLOSE dbCursor;
DEALLOCATE dbCursor;

SELECT * FROM #licenselist 

DROP TABLE #licenselist
```

**EDIT**: streamlined a bit, removed the raw @dbname variable and instead fixed it in the original query.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was hoping for, I did a little tweaking to only include the DB I wanted and the output displayed but this is just what I needed, thank you!

Comment: @Thorin and BradC: in the query to get the DB list, you should be using the `state_desc` column of `sys.databases` since you are already selecting from that system catalog view, rather than invoking a function to get that same value in a round-about way. Also, you should ideally also check permissions via another WHERE condition checking [HAS_DBACCESS ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/has-dbaccess-transact-sql).

Comment: Good improvements, @SolomonRutzky. `DATABASEPROPERTYEX` was probably left over from older versions of my script that used the (now deprecated) `sysdatabases`, which doesn't have that column. Since I no longer have any SQL 2000 servers (yeah!) I can remove it. As a DBA, `HAS_DBACCESS` will always be 1 for me, but I can see the utility in a general use script.

Comment: @Thorin and BradC: understood on both counts, and looks good. Thanks! P.S. Regarding `HAS_DBACCESS` and being a DBA, yeah, the idea is that queries like this become templates pasted into all scripts, prior to dealing with who will execute it, so I like having it there as it doesn't hurt and helps prevent errors that break the process when pasted into a general-use script :-).

Comment: @SolomonRutzky [So it looks like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/has-dbaccess-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  `HAS_DBACCESS` isn't just a permission check, and could even replace our `state_desc = 'ONLINE'` filter entirely, since it returns `0` if the database is offline or suspect.

Comment: @BradC Yes and no. I did not mention the potential removal of `state_desc = 'ONLINE'` because that is more restrictive than what `HAS_DBACCESS` is doing. Checking for "online" is highly specific, and excludes certain states that are not necessarily clear in whether or not you can actually access the DB. There are 1 or 2 states that require an additional check for `collation_name IS NOT NULL` to be certain. Maybe "recovering" or something? But filtering for "online" side-steps that nuance, so I figured it was fine as is. But if you remove it, you need to add that additional check.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again, slightly modified to only query the DB I wanted and output only results with YES.

```
--Create a table to hold the query results
CREATE TABLE #licenselist
    (dbname sysname, system_license varchar(99));

DECLARE @dbname SYSNAME;
DECLARE @fixedname nvarchar(150);

--Include or exclude whatever databases you want
DECLARE dbCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases
    WHERE DATABASEPROPERTYEX(name, 'Status') = 'ONLINE'
    AND name like 'SOMETHING_%'
    AND name not like '%_SOMETHINGELSE'
    --AND name NOT IN ('master','msdb','model','tempdb');

OPEN dbCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor INTO @dbname;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       --Fix for invalid characters in DB names
       SELECT @fixedname = REPLACE(QUOTENAME(@dbname),'''','''''');     
       EXEC ('USE ' + @fixedname + ';' + 
        'INSERT INTO #licenselist
         SELECT DB_NAME() as dbname, ParamValue as system_license
         FROM TABLE1 
         WHERE paramname = ''STRING_VALUE'';');

       FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor INTO @dbname;
END;   

CLOSE dbCursor;
DEALLOCATE dbCursor;

SELECT *
FROM #licenselist
where system_license='YES'
ORDER by dbname desc

DROP TABLE #licenselist
```